# quick directory snapshot/hash

Tags: hash, directory, comparison, snapshot

I'm looking for pointers to solutions for a problem that must have been solved multiple times (or pointers to the proper terms to search for):

How to get a reasonably quick/cheap directory snapshot/hash that can be used to determine whether something has changed compared to a previous state (which can be during a previous run of the code)?

Edit: I'm thinking here in the 1st place of added or deleted files/directories, but also of file changes that can be determined without reading the entire file.

Edit2: I'm looking for something cross-platform, and not a notification mechanism (sadly).

Thanks!

Comment: `... determine whether something has changed` please define "something"

Comment: Thanks, somehow I forgot to add that crucial tidbit.

Comment: Before inventing your own, please take a look at inotofy.

Comment: Clearly I also forgot to clarify that I wasn't looking for a change notification mechanism, and for a cross-platform solution. I'll need to stop posting when I cannot engage my brain at 200% ...